# php mysql populate several dynamic dropdown list with add button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

well this is my first post :)
I have a mysql DB and a form where you chose what you want to order. I have to say, that for input fields it works, but I have a problem when it comes to dynamic dropdowns. This is what I have (the two queries):

```
<?php
// Getting the data from mySQL table for first list box
$quer1="SELECT DISTINCT kategorija FROM artikli order by kategorija"; 

// for second dropdown list we will check if category is selected else we will display all the subcategories

if(isset($kategorija) and strlen($kategorija) > 0) {
    $quer2="SELECT artikel FROM artikli where kategorija='$kategorija' order by artikel";
}
else {
    $quer2="SELECT artikel FROM artikli order by artikel"; 
}
?>

<form id="forma_narocilo" action="naroci.php" method="POST">
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <div>

        <select name="kategorija" id="kategorija" ><option value="">Izberi kategorijo</option>
        <?php
            foreach ($dbo->query($quer1) as $row2) {
                if($row2['kategorija']==$kategorija) {
                    echo "<option id='izbirna_kategorija' selected value='$row2[kategorija]' onchange='self.location=self.location+'?kategorija='+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value'>$row2[kategorija]</option>"."<br />";
                }
                else {
                    echo  "<option id='izbirna_kategorija' value='$row2[kategorija]'>$row2[kategorija]</option>";
                }
            }
            echo "</select>";

            echo "<select name='artikel[]'><option value=''>Izberi artikel</option>";
            foreach ($dbo->query($quer2) as $row) {
                echo  "<option value='$row[artikel]'>$row[artikel]</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";

?>
            <input type="number" name="kolicina[]"/><button class="add_field_button">Add line</button>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="shrani" value="Save" >
</form>
```

and this works just fine and it is updating the fields according to my needs, but now I need an "add" button which will insert another line with all three fields (category, item, nrPcs). For normal html inputs I used this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var max_fields  = 25; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper     = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button  = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
var x = 1; //initlal text box count

$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append('<div>'+x+'<input type="text" name="artikel[]"/><input type="text" name="kolicina[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">X</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
})
});
```

this will add a  and 2 inputs inside. for the reload I use this:

```
function reload(){
    var form = document.getElementById("forma_narocilo");
    var val = form.kategorija.options[form.kategorija.options.selectedIndex].value;
        self.location='?kategorija=' + val ;
    }
    function init(){
        document.getElementById("kategorija").onchange = reload;
    }
    window.onload = init;
```

Now, my question is, how can I insert dropdowns when clicking the add button? Of course it should work as the first one e.g. it has to be independent...

thanks, erik

Comment: shall the new selects have the same content (options) as the first two?

Comment: I would suggest to do a bigger refactoring of your code. Not that it's bad or wrong - not at all - but you're kind of stuck here and you will run into more problems if you continue that way. I'd shift all the logic to js, including the build ing of the first form.

Comment: well yeah... all the new selects need to have the same content.
something like the pic on [THIS LINK](http://www.erijas.com/share/1multiple_dropdowns.png) but it's hardcoded in there... and as I need the form to go up to x (curently 25 lines max) it becomes ugly if I do this way :)
and yeah, I'm kind of stuck :/

Comment: I think the strategy should be to have the categories and articles as js-array, and build the form completely in js. no need for a page-reload then, easier to add a new line, ...

Comment: OK, i did it :) I have a different approach now... using ajax calls to populate the fields. and it works like a charm.